# Elasticsearch performRequestAsync how to return response to upper caller

Tags: java, elasticsearch

The Following is what I copy from Elasticsearch Official website

"The Response object, either returned by the synchronous performRequest methods or received as an argument in ResponseListener#onSuccess(Response), wraps the response object returned by the http client"

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/_reading_responses.html

The following is Async Function in ElasticSearchService Class
    public void getAsyncRequest(String endpoint, Map params, HttpEntity entity) {

```
    restClient.performRequestAsync("GET", endpoint, params, entity, new ResponseListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Response response) {
            try {
                LOGGER.info(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

The following is another Class.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ElasticSearchService.getAsyncRequest(endpoint, params, entity);
}
```

So my question is, when calling getAsyncRequestWithBody, when it is onSuccess, then it will get response Object, but how do I return it back to the caller which is static "main" function.

I didn't figure out what it means by "wraps the response object returned by the http client"

Thank you for help.
leochung

Answer (score 0):

Your java code very likely exits, before the response is processed. You can use the `RestClient.SyncResponseListener` to wait for the response to return.

But you are basically not gaining anything from an async call in this example. If you underlying code does not support it, you can just keep using the synchronous code.